# Instruction-level debugging of .NET files

Tags: .net, assemblies, reverse-engineering, cil

I am looking for a instruction-level virtual machine debugger for debugging .NET files. The files are release builds and disassembling and then recompiling them is not an option.

Comment: Do you mean CIL or assembler instructions?

Comment: That's correct. I want to debug the CIL (MSIL) instructions, the instructions of .NET's virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

[Deblector](http://deblector.codeplex.com/) - debugging plugin for Reflector

Also Pro version of [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is a VS addin that allows

> Step into decompiled assemblies and use all the debugging techniques you would use on your own code